# Build a dictionary app for iphone based on StarDict

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need some information on how to build an iPhone dictionary app based on [StarDict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarDict) e.g. Wedict.

How does one import [idx files](http://stardict.sourceforge.net/StarDictFileFormat) into a tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess that the idx files are to big and complex to efficiently use on the iPhone (except for smaller specialized dictionaries.) The iPhone Stardict apps probably connect to an online server so I suggest starting with the [StarDict Server Protocol](http://stardict.sourceforge.net/StarDict-Protocol).

Most of the work on this will involve getting the StarDict provided information from the idx files or online. Only when you've reached the point where you can get the plain, human readable text of a query result should you start thinking about how to get that text into a UITableView.